# How can I get the top 1 value of an aggregate query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Consider the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 discountAmount,
       SUM(amount)
FROM customerTransactions
WHERE customerTrasactions.id = 123
ORDER BY discountAmount DESC
```

This query definitely will not work, because I am not grouping by discountAmount, but all I want is the sum total of amounts for the customer in question, plus their greatest discount amount.

Is there a way I can do this without having to resort to a subquery or a cross apply? This is a small part of a much larger query that I am trying to optimize, so being able to get these two datapoints in a single query like this would be optimal.

I am unfortunatly constricted to SQL Server 2008

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT TOP (1) discountAmount,
       SUM(amount) OVER () as sum
FROM customerTransactions
WHERE customerTrasactions.id = 123
ORDER BY discountAmount DESC;
```

The window function provides the sum over all rows *that would be returned*.  That is, the window function is evaluated before the `ORDER BY` or `TOP (1)`.

Comment: I believe this works! However, I did not know you could use an OVER clause without any other criteria; what exactly does this do? I don't quite understand it.